# Railway programming F#

Tags: f#

I am trying to use the railway programming in F# using result as described in Scott Wlaschin's book 'Domain modeling made functional'. Normally a function has the structure

```
let functionName parameter : Result<ResultType, ErrorType> =
    result {
        let! resultValue = someValidationAndTransformation parameter
        return resultValue
    }
```

But I want to return also some calculated fields, in both to Ok and the Error case. The best I could come up with was

```
let functionName parameter : Result<ResultType, ErrorType> * CalculatedFields =
    let mutable calculatedFields = {some defaultvalue}
    let result = 
        result {
            let! resultValue = someValidationAndTransformation parameter
            let calculatedField = someCalculation resultValue
            calculatedFields <- {calculatedFields with calculatedField}
            return resultValue
        }
    result, calculatedFields
```

This mutable field does not look nice. Is there a better way to get the calculated fields in both Ok and Error case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a `match` in this situation:

```ml
let functionName parameter : Result<ResultType, ErrorType> * CalculatedFields =
  let result = someValidationAndTransformation parameter

  let calculatedFields = 
    match result with
    | Ok x -> someCalculation x
    | Error e -> { some defaultvalue }

  result, calculatedFields
```

Comment: My pseudo code sample is somewhat simplistic version of the real code, but the real code could be restructured to your sample which is more understandable than intertwining the result{..} expresion with the calculation of the calculatedfields.

Comment: If you have something more complicated then nesting `result` workflows as you have tried is perfectly valid. You can also switch a `let!` to a `let` if you need to handle both sides inside of a `result` workflow.

Comment: I know, but when I tried my initial solution without declaring the mutable variable before the result{..} expression, the last statement does not recognize the calculatedFields (which would then be defined inside the result{..} expression)